# How can I resize Betheme header

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress-theming

I am using Wordpress Betheme. When I scroll the mouse the menu bar becomes small size, but, initially the size is big. How can I fix it? I mean I want the menu bar sticky and it always remains smaller like the scrolling size. I don't want a large header. Just a small size header will always remains and there will be no effect when scrolling.

Theme Link:
http://themes.muffingroup.com/betheme/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a "is-sticky" class which sets the style to the header you need. Unfortunately this class is added and removed by some JavaScript of the theme.

According to the [BeTheme Documentation](http://themes.muffingroup.com/betheme/documentation/#header), there should be an option to turn on and off the sticky header.

If this turns the JavaScript oft, you could manualy set the "is-sticky" class to the element with the id "Top_bar", to always have the smaller menu bar.

Alternatively, adapt the css of the "is-sticky" class and add it to your header manually as the default style for "#Top_bar" and its inner elements.

Comment: Thank You. Yes, there is an option to turn on and off the sticky header. But there is no option to menu bar resizing. When the page is landing the menu bar is big, but after scrolling it becomes smaller than initial size. I want to make same size after landing and when scrolling. I could't fint any option to rsize header or menu bar.

Comment: With my approach you would need to add the "is-sticky" class manually to the HTML as described, but after turning the option off (As it would remove the is-sticky class on scrolling). Alternatively you need to add my mentioned alternative way to your custom css.